# Gocardless - Redirect flow in Node JS

Tags: node.js, redirect, gocardless

I'm trying to use Gocardless to enable SEPA payment in my website.
The example in the API doc doesn't work and seems uncomplete

POST https://api.gocardless.com/redirect_flows HTTP/1.1

```
{
  "redirect_flows": {
    "description": "Wine boxes",
    "session_token": "SESS_wSs0uGYMISxzqOBq",
    "success_redirect_url": "https://example.com/pay/confirm",
    "prefilled_customer": {
      "given_name": "Frank",
      "family_name": "Osborne",
      "email": "frank.osborne@acmeplc.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The example is working correctly for me. What error or response are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

That's the response I get :

{
    "error": {
        "message": "not found",
        "errors": [
            {
                "reason": "not_found",
                "message": "not found"
            }
        ],
        "documentation_url": "https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference#not_found",
        "type": "invalid_api_usage",
        "request_id": "7ae43821-345d-4ffd-98d6-15c4fe5513e6",
        "code": 404
    }
}

How can it work if the access token of the application is never asked for the request ?

Comment: Are you sure you're making a POST request? You do need the access token in the request headers: https://developer.gocardless.com/api-reference/#api-usage-making-requests